# adjust border on one specific side

Tags: wpf, border, controltemplates

I'm using a controlTemplate of the ListBox to show a collection. 
I want to display all the items with a border like in a grid (all lines same size). 
When I give every listBoxItem a border, the line between 2 items has a double size. 
(made from the bottom border of the first item, and the top border of the second item)

So the question is:
Can I set/hide the border on a single side of an item? (like 'border-top' in css)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The border property is a thickness, just like margin and padding, so you can do Border="2,0,2,2" to get a border of 2 everywhere except the top.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed for my SplitView Grid for Hamburger Menu in UWP. :)