# What are the standard ways to put a crisp partial border around a WPF element?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-interface

If I have a menu bar in WPF and I set its Border to be black and have thickness 1, I get a crsip 1 pixel border all the way around the menu bar, instead of just a nice crisp line at the bottom. Similarly for a status bar. How can I get a nice crisp boundary around just part of a WPF element like a menu bar or status bar?

Having crisp 1 pixel border around parts of element boundaries is so common there must be some standard ways of doing this. What are they?

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499607/adjust-border-on-one-specific-side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not not 100% sure I understand your question, but what I think your're looking for is a border that is visible just on the bottom of an element.  You can accomplish this with the [BorderThickness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.borderthickness.aspx) property:

```
BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
```

That will set the left, top and right borders to 0 and the bottom to 1.  If you set ...

```
BorderThickness="1"
```

that is the same as ...

```
BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a Border? If so...

```
<Border Name="myBorder" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,2,2">
 <!-- your stuff here -->
</Border>
```